# App crashes when removing data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on events feature for my app and I've been stuck with this bug for 2 days.

To summarize, I log into the app and retrieve an *eventid* from Firebase which I set as a static *User.eventid*. When the app switches to MainActivity, the static User.eventid is used to decide which fragment to use: ViewEventsFragment or DefaultEventFragment (Empty fragment with 2 buttons). **If** ***User.eventid="null"***, go to **DefaultEventFragment**, **else** go to **ViewEventsFragment**.

**Initially**, the user is in an event so **User.eventid="LyfLmM...."** Thus MainActivity will take the user to **ViewEventsFragment.** Now, in ViewEventsFragment, I have an option to **delete** an event. Upon doing so, I update the firebase eventid="null" for future logins **and** update the static **User.eventid="null"** to be used in MainActivity. Then the intent is launched and the user is taken to MainActivity where the app will decide which fragment to switch to depending on User.eventid. Since I just changed the static User.eventid="null", I should be taken to DefaultEventsActivity.

But that doesn't work and my app crashes instead. I included code from start to finish and the error logs.

LoginActivity.class

```
// Retrieve information about the user from Firebase. One important field is eventid which represents 
// the event that the user is part of. If eventid=="null", then the user is not in any event.

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
eventid = obj.getJSONObject(id).getString("eventid");
User.eventid = eventid;
...
startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class));
```

MainActivity.class

```
 // Once the user is taken to MainActivity, there is a bottom navigation that loads a fragment 
 // depending on the User.eventid retrieved in Login. If the user is an event, take them to 
 // ViewEventsFragment. if user is NOT in event, take them to DefaultEventsFragment

 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
     Fragment fragment;
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.event_button:

                    Log.i("ViewEventsFragment", "MainActivity: "+User.eventid);

                    if(User.eventid.equals("null")) {
                        fragment = fragmentA;
                    }
                    else {
                        fragment = fragmentB;
                    }
                    break;
            ...
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Asssume that the user is part of an event. Then we load:

ViewEventsFragment.java

```
// In this fragment, the user is part of an event. This means that User.eventid is NOT "null" and 
// user was redirected here from MainActivity. So first pull all the
// data from firebase to populate the fields

Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());
pullFirebaseData();

// Pull data from firebase and populate fields
// This function should only be called if eventid is NOT null
// But for some reason, it's being called while it's null and gets an error
public void pullFirebaseData(){

    eventid = User.eventid;    
    if((eventid==null) || (eventid.equals("null"))){
        User.eventid = "null";
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
    }  

    Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://...firebaseio.com/events");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            **Line144** name = dataSnapshot.child(eventid).child("eventName").getValue().toString();
            date = dataSnapshot.child(eventid).child("eventDate").getValue().toString();
            time = dataSnapshot.child(eventid).child("eventTime").getValue().toString();
            ...
 }

// Suppose now user wants to delete the event. 
leaveGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // (1) First update Firebase by changing each users eventid to "null". This works. 
            // (2) Now, change User.eventid="null" since user is leaving the event and switch to 
            //     MainActivity. Since the User.eventid="null", the user SHOULd be taken to 
            //     DefaultEventsFragment and NOT back here. 
            // (3) Finally, delete the event from Firebase

                (1) changeAllUserFirebase();
                (2) User.eventid = "null"
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                (3) deleteEvent();
            }
        }
    });

// Remove the entire event from Firebase
public void deleteEvent(){
    Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://grouptracker-ef84c.firebaseio.com/events");
    reference.child(User.eventid).removeValue();
}
```

Now the problem starts. As seen by the logs, I'm successfully getting an eventid in MainActivity and switching to ViewEventFragment. Now when I try to delete it, it takes me BACK to ViewEventsFragments when it's supposed to take me to MainActivity instead.

```
2020-01-15 17:40:15.514 18350-18350/com.package.appname I/ViewEventsFragment: MainActivity: -LyfLmMmO1mkB0gvB9P7

2020-01-15 16:38:24.905 17166-17166/com.package.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package.appname, PID: 17166
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.package.appname.Fragments.ViewEventsFragment$4.onDataChange(ViewEventsFragment.java:144)
    at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

So I've tested it by taking out deleteEvent() and it works perfectly. I get switched to MainACtivity ==> DefaultEventFragment. Now I'm confused as to why deleting the event from firebase crashes my app.

Attempt: So I tried moving the deleteEvent() function to Main instead. So once the user leaves the event, it goes from ViewEventsFragment to Main. Then in Main, it should delete the event. However, the app just goes back to ViewEventsFragment and crashes. Not sure what's causing it to forcefully go to ViewEventsFragment.

Comment: where is this line `ViewEventsFragment.java:144`? the error is in this line, with `toString()`

Comment: Please indicate the exact line of code at which the error occurs.

Comment: I updated with the lines. The code shouldn't even go to this line since I'm deleting the event and calling an intent to switch to another activity. But for some reason, instead of going to MainActivity, it just reloads the activity and results in an error.

Comment: The error is expected since it's trying to retrieve a String from something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*When you register the listener with reference.addValueEventListener it's going to call onDataChange every time the data you're listening to changes, including when that data gets deleted, meaning it will be called with null. You should either handle the possibility of the data being gone, or unregister your listener before deleting the data using removeEventListener and passing in the same instance of ValueEventListener.*"

-AngusMcBurger from Reddit

---

Since I was deleting data, my listener was always reading new changes and with the data being gone, it was fetching something that didn't exist. Based on the logic above, I restructured my code and made a new listener:

```
final Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://....firebaseio.com/...");

final ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            name = dataSnapshot.child(eventid).child("eventName").getValue().toString();
            ...
            nameTextView.setText(name);
            ...
        }
    };
    // Here, I'm registering the listener
    reference.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
}

// *IMPORTANT*
leaveGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           ...
           // I'm done with the listener so now I'm removing it
           reference.removeEventListener(eventListener);                 
        }
}
```